# How can I disable Alt-F4 and Ctrl-Alt-Del by using hooking?

Tags: vb.net, winapi

How can I disable Alt-F4 and Ctrl-Alt-Del?

Can I lock all combinations of a key with the Alt key?

I got a sample from the internet, it only can disable Alt+Tab, Alt+Esc, Ctrl+Esc, Windows Key

```
Select Case wParam
        Case 256, 257, 260, 261
            'Alt+Tab, Alt+Esc, Ctrl+Esc, Windows Key     
            blnEat = ((lParam.vkCode = 9) AndAlso (lParam.flags = 32)) Or _
            ((lParam.vkCode = 27) AndAlso (lParam.flags = 32)) Or _
            ((lParam.vkCode = 27) AndAlso (lParam.flags = 0)) Or _
            ((lParam.vkCode = 91) AndAlso (lParam.flags = 1)) Or _
            ((lParam.vkCode = 92) AndAlso (lParam.flags = 1))
    End Select
```

Where can I see the button code list in `lParam.vkCode = ??`?
How can I make it able to disable Alt-F4 and Ctrl-Alt-Del or disable all combinations of a key with the Alt key?

Answer (score 2):

You can't intercept CTRL+ALT+DEL. It's known as the secure attention key and if an app could intercept it then the computer's security would be compromised.

What you can do is to configure
Windows to ignore Ctrl+Alt+Del by disabling task manager: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811991.aspx

There's no reason why you shouldn't be able to intercept ALT+F4 but it's hard to advise you since you haven't been completely clear in your question. In particular the code you present is out of context and I can't guess to which events it runs in response.

If you are looking for the [key code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft8xdf67.aspx) for F4 then it is `&H73`. I strongly recommend you use the standard named constants rather than hard coded literal values, e.g. `vbKeyF4`.

Comment: can i change the registry to disable alt+ctrl+del when app load?

Comment: Not that I know of, and I'd be very surprised if you could do this. This question is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable the ctrl-alt-delete combination because it never reaches the application-level. It is handled by the OS, and OS only!

You'd be better off ripping the keys off your keyboard. Nevertheless, there are ways to bypass this restriction, like writing your own keyboard driver or through a Gina stub.

Comment: Gina won't get you anywhere these days, it no longer exists in Vista/7.

Comment: @David true, except he didn't specifically say it wasn't for NT < 5

Comment: @freedompeace you didn't state that limitation either, my comment remedies that omission

Comment: can i disable alt ctrl del and alt f4 in windows xp sp3??

Comment: @e-qi, yes you can. But not through the usual hook you're used to. The above methods will work.

Comment: It can be disabled in xp via GPO; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc188951.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is true that you cannot capture Ctrl+Alt+Del combination even with global keyboard hooks because it is directly transmitted to OS, but you can easily trick this. I am not sure about your whole problem but I am thinking that you want to disable the Task Manager while your application is running.

Steps:

1. Onload event of our application start task manager in hidden mode (Now if user presses Ctrl+Alt+Del nothing will happen).
2. OnClose Event of your application simply close Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

**Disable Alt + f4, It Works!**

> ```
>     Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
>     Get
>         Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
>         Const CS_NOCLOSE As Integer = &H200
>         cp.ClassStyle = cp.ClassStyle Or CS_NOCLOSE
>         Return cp
>     End Get
> End Property
> ```